# 0.5 Divided by 1, stages to answer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

It may seem pretty simple, but it just doesn't make any sense to me. Dividing any positive decimal under 1 by 1 but just getting the same decimal back? I would like it if someone explained to me how this works.

Comment: You can edit your post by pressing the edit button below the question.

Comment: I've edited the tags - "logic" refers to a specific subfield of mathematics, which this isn't. The most appropriate tag is "arithmetic". I've also added the tag "algebra-precalculus," since - although the specific question doesn't involve variables - the underlying issue I believe is one of algebra; feel free to remove that tag if you disagree.

Comment: If you take half a pie and divide it into 1 piece, how big is each piece?

Comment: Are you saying that you don't have any trouble understanding that $2\div 1 = 2,$ $3\div 1 = 3,$ $1.5\div 1 = 1.5,$ and $1.1\div 1 = 1.1,$ you only doubt the result when it is less than $1$?

Comment: Everything divided by 1 is itself.  Everything.  And everything multiplied by 1 is itself.  Everything.  1 is the multiplicative/division unit-identy.  Dividing any amount into 1 group is .... to put everything you've got into one group... maybe your confusion is with the word "divide".  In english, we can't "divide" by 1 because "divide" means to cut into smaller piece**s** and so we can't "divide" into only one whole piece.  But that's exactly what we do mean in math.  Divide by one = put in one group = leave it by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Students are told:

1. when you divide by a number *greater* than 1, the answer is *smaller* than what you started with, and
2. when divide by a number *less* than 1, the answer is *larger* than what you started with.

If you're sharp, you'll notice that these statements omit 1 itself. What happens if you divide by a number *exactly* 1? It's the same as multiplying by its reciprocal. But the reciprocal of 1 is 1! So dividing by 1 is the same as multiplying by 1. And by now you should know that 1 is called the **multiplicative identity**, which is how graduate students express the fact that multiplying by 1 does not change the other number: $a \times 1 = a$. Therefore, since multiplying by 1 is the same as dividing by 1, then dividing 0.5 (or any other real number) by 1 will be 0.5.

Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Think of division as a question: "$a\over b$" is asking, "What do I need to multiply by $b$ to get $a$?"

Now, $1$ has the lovely property that it makes multiplication boring: $1\cdot x=x=x\cdot 1$. So anytime I ask "What do I need to multiply $1$ by to get $x$?", the answer is always . . . $x$! If I multiply $1$ by something $z$ **other** than $x$, I'll get $z$, not $x$.

So ${0.5\over 1}$ is the number you need to multiply $1$ by to get $0.5$. That's just $0.5$ itself!

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way.  You have $31$ oranges and you need to put them into $6$ bags.  How many oranges go into each bag?  That is the practical meaning of $31 \div 6$.  $x \div y$ means if we divide $x$ into $y$ equal parts, how big is each part?

Okay, what if we want to put $x$ into $1$ bag? Just **!$1$!** bag.  Well, that $1$ bag gets .... everything.  $x \div 1 = x$.  You have just one bag in which to put everything so... that one bag will *have* everything.

So you have $1/2$ an orange.  You put it into $1$ bag.  How many oranges are in that bag?  ... Um.  $1/2$... right?

Answer (score 0):

Division is the opposite of multiplication, so the two equations
$$
c = a \times b  
$$
and 
$$
\frac{c}{b} = a
$$
say the same thing (as long as $b \ne 0$).

When $b=1$ each equation says $c=a$. There's nothing special happening when $a$ is less than $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the property $${{a\over b}\over {c\over d}}={a\cdot d\over b\cdot c}$$

Then look that $0.5={1\over2}$, so if you replace it, it will be like $${{1\over 2}\over {1\over 1}}={1\cdot1\over 1\cdot2}={1\over 2}$$